# article content not showing in joomla 2.5 after upgrading from 1.5 to 2.5

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla1.5

I have an issue with my joomla 2.5 site.

I upgrade my site from joomla 1.5 to 2.5 version. After upgrading, articles not displaying.

It shows the article heading but not showing the content. I give the permissions to the site but it doesn't works.

Comment: Have u checked the global article settings?

Comment: @Arunu yes.I checked that

Comment: check if this link helps http://docs.joomla.org/Disappearing_articles_after_2.5_upgrade  http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=2729231

Comment: @Arunu I can't get the solution from there.In these links,they are telling about "unpublished contact linked to user" . There is no contact in my site.

Comment: try adding a new article and link it to a menu and check if content get displayed or not?i mean in joomla2.5

Comment: @Arunu i tried that but not displaying.It only displays the menu title in the page

Comment: @arunu this is the site : http://keralacarpentry.com/freedom2/

Comment: Check ur database table  #_content and confirm data is there in introtext column

Comment: @Arunu yes.contents are shown in the introtext coloumn of content table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the real solution

that is : go to the jupgrade/template/html folder and delete or rename the com_content folder

Then it will work properly

Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

Your site has following url structure  http://keralacarpentry.com/freedom2/index.php?Itemid=2

But joomla component url structure is like this   http://www.example.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=29. Check ur joomla 1.5 site url and compare it with 2.5 url

Comment: That url is for an alias type.

Answer (score 1):

GO TO YOUR OLD joomla 1.5 template folder, look for html folder and rename com_content folder to anything else. Article content shall show up.